# "or" conditional in Python troubles

Tags: python, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm learning Python and I'm having a little bit of a problem. Came up with this short script after seeing something similar in a course I'm taking. I've used "or" with "if" before with success (it doesn't show much here). For some reason I can't seem to get this working:

```
test = raw_input("It's the flying circus! Cool animals but which is the best?")
x = test.lower()

if x == "monkey" or "monkeys":
    print "You're right, they are awesome!!"
elif x != "monkey" or "monkeys":
    print "I'm sorry, you're incorrect.", x[0].upper() + x[1:], "is not the right animal."
```

But this works great:

```
test = raw_input("It's the flying circus! Cool animals but which is the best?")
x = test.lower()

if x == "monkey":
    print "You're right, they are awesome!!"
elif x != "monkey":
    print "I'm sorry, you're incorrect.", x[0].upper() + x[1:], "is not the right animal."
```

Probably the or conditional does not fit here. But I've tried and, etc. I'd love a way to make this accept monkey or monkeys and everything else triggers the elif.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Boolean expressions in most programming languages don't follow the same grammar rules as English. You have to do separate comparisons with each string, and connect them with `or`:

```
if x == "monkey" or x == "monkeys":
    print "You're right, they are awesome!!"
else:
    print "I'm sorry, you're incorrect.", x[0].upper() + x[1:], "is not the right animal."
```

You don't need to do the test for the incorrect case, just use `else`. But if you did, it would be:

```
elif x != "monkey" and x != "monkeys"
```

Do you remember learning about [deMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) in logic class? They explain how to invert a conjunction or disjunction.

Comment: Thank you SO much that works and terrific information, helps me grasp it a lot better now!

Answer (score 8):

gkayling is correct.  Your first if statement returns true if:

x == "monkey"

or

"monkeys" evaluates to true (it does since it's not a null string).

When you want to test if x is one of several values, it's convenient to use the "in" operator:

```
test = raw_input("It's the flying circus! Cool animals but which is the best?")
x = test.lower()

if x in ["monkey","monkeys"]:
    print "You're right, they are awesome!!"
else:
    print "I'm sorry, you're incorrect.", x[0].upper() + x[1:], "is not the right
```

Comment: Very cool, I didn't even know about that in operator. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Should be
`if x == "monkey" or x == "monkeys":`