# Not sure why my if statements to check the first character of varaible state is only running the first statement

Tags: python, if-statement, character

I know my code is a little messy, I am going to clean it up once I can figure out why the if statements to check state[0] is only printing the first statement. I tried moving it around the codeblocks and indentations but still only getting the first if statement to print. Any advice/help would be great. Just came back to python, been learning java/SQL, this class is going back to python, so I'm a little off at then moment. Thanks

```
ballotLoop = input("Hey there, are you here for the voter ballot? Exit to stop.\n")
```

while ballotLoop != "exit":

```
lastName = input("Please enter your last name.\n")

firstName = input("Please enter your first name.\n")

age = int(input("Please enter your age.\n"))

usCit = input("Are you a United States Citizen?\n")



if usCit == "yes":
    if age >= 18 and age < 80:
        print(firstName, lastName +". Great you are over 18 and a US citizen\nYou may proceed with the form.\n")
       
    elif age > 0 and age < 18:
        print("I am sorry you are not old enough to complete this voter form.")

    elif age > 80:
         print("Error age does not make sense.\n")
         
    elif age < -1:
        print("Error age does not make sense.\n")

    state = input("What state do you currently reside in?\n")

    zipcode = input("What is your current zipcode\n")
        
    print("Alright so to make sure everything is correct we have the following.\n"\
          + firstName, lastName + ", you are "+ str(age) + " years old.\nYou marked " + usCit + \
          " for being a US citizen.\nYou currently reside in " + state + " and your zipcode is " + zipcode +"\n")

    if state[0]  == "a" or "c":
             print("You should recieve your ballot in 1 week")
        
    elif state[0] == "t" or "d":
             print("You should recieve your ballot in 4 weeks")
            
    elif state[0] == "m" or "l":
             print("You should recieve your ballot in 2 weeks")

    
elif usCit == "no":
    print("I am sorry but you may not complete this form, I am going to have to ask you to leave.")
    

ballotLoop = input("Would you like to fill out another ballot? Exit to stop.\n")

if ballotLoop == "exit":
    print("Thank you for you vote today, every little bit makes a difference!!")
```

Comment: Your conditions should be written as `if state[0]  == "a" or state[0]  == "c"`. Otherwise, it checks whether `"c"` is true, which it is (non-empty string).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["or" conditional in Python troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375793/or-conditional-in-python-troubles)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** 
`state[0]  == "a" or state[0]  == "c"` 
 instead of 
`state[0]  == "a" or "c"` 
and so on for next two logics.

**Explanation**

There are two parts per `and` / `or` keywords in python. The *left part* (any [boolean expression](https://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/boolean.html)) to the keyword is compared with the *right part* (another boolean expression). And you know that boolean expression is either True or False.
Keeping these in mind let's break down your if statement.

```py
if state[0]  == "a" or "c":
    print('...')
```

Here, the boolean expressions are:

1. `state[0]  == "a"`
   Possible results: Either True or False
2. `"c"` which is always True in python. [Check this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp).

So under the hood your logical operation in the if statement is 
`state[0] == "a" or True`
Which will always return `True`, satisfying the first if statement everytime.
Long story short, explicitly write:
`state[0]  == "a" or state[0]  == "c"`